# Rendering pre-existing graph in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, visualization

I am trying to use the SelectInput in my UserInterface file, and trying to render a graph when user has selected a plot but i end up with errors. Can someone please help?

Code:

```
camden <- read_excel("G:/camden.xlsx")
 kingston <- read_excel("G:/kingston1.xlsx")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$dynamicPlot <- renderPlot({
    if(input$visual_id == 'Camden'){
      camden = ggplot(df, aes(x = SpeciesCode, y = Year)) + geom_point()
      camden + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust =1))
    camden + ggtitle("Camden") + xlab("Air Pollutants") + ylab("Measured year")
    }

    if(input$visual_id == 'Kingston'){
      kingston = ggplot(df, aes(x = SpeciesDescription, y = Year)) + geom_point()
    }
    camden
  })

})
```

UI.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Data Visualisation"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       selectInput('visual_id', label='Please select area of visualisation',
                   choices=c("Kingston1", "Camden"), selected = "Camden")),


    # Show a plot of the "generated distribution
    mainPanel("main panel",

              plotOutput('dynamicPlot'))

  )
)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Generate a test dataset
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(SpeciesDescription= LETTERS,
                 SpeciesCode = paste0("ID.",LETTERS),
                 Year=sample(1992:2017, 26))

ui <- fluidPage(
       titlePanel("Data Visualisation"),
       sidebarLayout( 
         sidebarPanel( 
           selectInput('visual_id', label='Please select area of visualisation', 
                     choices=c("Kingston", "Camden"), selected = "Camden")),
         mainPanel("main panel", plotOutput('dynamicPlot'))
       )
      ) 

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$dynamicPlot <- renderPlot({
    if(input$visual_id == 'Camden') {
      p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = SpeciesCode, y = Year)) + geom_point() +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust =1)) +
       ggtitle("Camden") + xlab("Air Pollutants") + ylab("Measured year")
    }
    if(input$visual_id == 'Kingston') {
      p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = SpeciesDescription, y = Year)) + geom_point()
    }
    p
  })    
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: getting the error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: kingston and camden are xls files that i am trying to use to create graphs in my shiny app

Comment: @R07 It works in my R (with a test dataset). Your datasets should collapsed into the `df' data frame. Please, share your code about the `df' object

Comment: also, when i select the inputs, the graph does not show in Main panel for Kingston, however when camden is selected, it shows an error message

Comment: Okay, thankyou. I have managed to figure out what the issue is, when you mentioned about the dataframe, it works now.

Comment: @R07 OK, nice to help you. Please, upvote and accept my answer if you find it helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my code was

```
kingston = ggplot(df, aes(x = SpeciesDescription, y = Year)) + geom_point()
```

i need to declare the dataframe object name that i am calling from.

Comment: This is not the only problem in your code. For example, the output of your plots should have the same name (in my code `p'). Please, see the solution that I suggested in my answer.